# How to pass Java ArrayList to jQuery function?

Tags: java, javascript, jstl

I have a function which popup a modal window:

```
function showTable(employees) {
    var result = $('#empl');
    result.empty();
    $.each(employees, function (index, employee) {
        var tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append($('<td/>').html(employee.id));
        tr.append($('<td/>').html(employee.name));
        result.append(tr);
    });
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

And code which invoke this function:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="showTable(${company.employees})">View</button>
```

My `Company` class

```
public class Company implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> employees;
```

But function doesn't work. How to make it work?

Comment: Did you check the naming? Your JSP EL uses `employee` while your code states `employees`.

Comment: Yes. I updated it. The result is the same.

Comment: You realize that by the time the page renders, the EL has already been processed (server-side), right? `onclick="showTable(${company.employees})"` is NOT doing what you hope it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to convert your list of employees to JSON and pass the JSON string to the JavaScript function.

In order to do that have a look at the various JSON libraries out there, e.g. [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) [etc.](http://json.org/)

Comment: Than I can't use JSTL because of getters/setters. I can't wrap my POJO to json.

Comment: @Arkasha you must understand that all you can do here is create a JavaScript snapshot of your "Employee" object list. The Java/JSTL code runs on the **server** and the JavaScript runs on the **client**.

Comment: I can't understand how to wrap List to GSON. In my case I can't use getters and setters. So now the question is how to pass String to JSP (JSTL) without using set/getters? Is it possible?

Comment: @Arkasha you'd write a "pseudo-getter" that returns a JSON string, e.g. `String getEmployeeListJSON()` and use it like `showTable(${company.employeeListJSON})`.